# Versions of g++ called from zsh script and manually from terminal differ

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, g++, zsh

I recently installed `g++-10` with Homebew on my MacOS 10.14.6. I created an alias in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias g++="/usr/local/bin/g++-10"
```

to automated compile and run in terminal I created a `.sh` file. However, I noticed that the version of g++ used when calling g++ manually from terminal is the following:

```
$ g++ --version
g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

which is not the same than the one which calls g++ from the `.sh` script. The content of the script `displayg++Version.sh` is:

```
type g++
g++ --version
```

and then the output of the call of the script is:

```
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Here is the output of the following command:

```
$ type g++
g++ is an alias for /usr/local/bin/g++-10
```

Why do both versions differ?

Comment: Why does the question have a `bash` tag?

Comment: @Cyrus because I used bash and still have a bash profile in my machine so I don't know if it's related. I wrote the same alias there though. I can remove the tag if you want

Comment: Add output of `type g++` to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus. I just wrote as you asked

Comment: Does `zsh` use your `alias` in your script?

Comment: Thank you for your time @Cyrus: I'm not sure to understand the question, but the content of the script `displayg++Version.sh` is `g++ --version` (without `alias` in it). Does that help?

Comment: In the script, before running g++, try `type g++` and paste result.

Comment: @Philipp: by `$HOME/.zshrc` you mean the `.zshrc` file which can be accessed with `vim ~/.zshrc` (using vim). If yes there is no word `PATH` written in that file

Comment: `~/.zlogin` and `~/.zprofile` don't exist on my system

Comment: Do you mean re-run `$zsh displayg++Version.sh`. If yes, the output is still: `Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @Philippe. Thank you for your patience. The script `displayg++Version.sh` has already `type g++ g++ --version` (on 2 separate lines). So `type g++` is already at the beginning. I'm not sure to understand what change you want me to do to the script or which other command you want me to do

Comment: It's to understand why they use different versions.  Which g++ you WANT to use ?

Comment: Ok Let's say I want to use the version `g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, alias definitions are ignored in a script, unless explicitly enabled. You can turn this on by doing in your script a

```
setopt aliases
```

but don't forget that this affects only aliases which are defined **afterwards**, not before.

Second, .zshrc is not processed by a zsh script unless explicitly enabled. From the zsh man-page:

> If the shell is **interactive**, commands are read from  /etc/zshrc  and then ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.

You can force interactivity by running your script with the `-i` option:

```
zsh -i your_script.zsh
```

If you want a certain g++ version to be executed in your zsh script, the usual solution is however to adjust the PATH so that zsh can find the right version. For instance:

```
PATH=/your/path/to/g++:$PATH zsh your_script.zsh
```

If you always want this g++ version to be used, you would of course set your PATH in your .zshrc accordingly. Since your command shell is interactive, the .zshrc will be processed, and since PATH is an environment variable, your script will peruse this PATH withou your need to do anything special.